# Can't initialize source list in the Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have the strange problem with Autocomplete script. It's initialized well but it doesn't show a list when I start to write something in the input. It looks like this: http://gyazo.com/157079c3651130585c25d377b9115c25, so there isn't added this section http://gyazo.com/fa1fd40acad627f145fe3bed10a0daa4.

It doesn't work even if I use the code from API documenation:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({ source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ] });
```

What can be a reason?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: have you actually changed `.selector` to the real class from the input?

Comment: Yes, of course. It's initialized well, but there is no block with the list of options from Source.

Comment: ui css also? could you please set up a fiddle so we can test